# Creation of CAB-Packages for Windows Embedded Standard 7

Tags: installation, windows-embedded-7, cab

I'm trying to build a custom WES7 distribution and therefore include my own Application and Drivers. I want to integrate my applications in the configuration process with  the Image Configuration Editor, therefore it would be usefull to build a CAB file that is compatible to the installation process.

The CAB files include an update.cat, update.mun , a manifest file and the content that will be installed, either drivers or files, write them manually is not possible.

There is a tool "cabwiz" included in the Windows Embedded Compact toolkit, but I couldn't test it.
Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all those searching for the same terms as I did. In WES7 you [don't create CAB files,](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/6/2/862977E5-8D21-4A1C-8DC9-C2289244C14C/Componentization%20of%20Device%20Drivers%20in%20Windows%20Embedded%20Standard%207.pdf) only Microsoft does. This is only a reference how they did it, not a manual.

Instead you have to add files to the Out-of-Box and the `$OEM$` folder.

Comment: Interesting find, I would have figured there was some sort of nLite-like utility. At least it seems pretty easy to do.